# How to override Octopress path on a per project basis in sublime text 2?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2, octopress

I recently install `octopress` as my blog platform as well as [Sublime Text 2 Octopress](https://github.com/blueplanet/sublime-text-2-octopress) plugin to simplify generation, deployment and others tasks.

### Default settings

The default settings (`octopress.sublime-settings`) are the followings:

```
// path to your octopress
"octopress_path": "/you_octopress_path",
```

### Project settings

However when I try to override them with a [per-project settings](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html) in `/home/me/projects/blog.sublime-project` (the parent directory):

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/home/me/projects/blog"
        }
    ],
  "settings":
  {
    // path to your octopress
    "octopress_path": "/home/me/projects/blog"
  }
}
```

### Running `generate` task

When I run the `generate` command from `sublime text 2`, I got the following error:

```
Starting to generate...
octopress exec start.
source ~/.zshrc; bundle exec rake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 339, in run_
  File "./octopress.py", line 161, in run
  File "./octopress.py", line 28, in exec_command
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/you_octopress_path/'
```

### Question

1. So how come it doesn't take my config into account and fallback to default?
2. How to override Octopress path on a per project basis in sublime text 2?